# The API Sandbox

Tags: support, api, sandbox

This is the same concept as [the first sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122).

Why do we need more than one? This is in order to test the API, some methods support vectored ids (for example `/questions/id1;id2/comments`) and for that two sandboxes are needed.

[image]

Comment: This is an edited comment.

Comment: Test comment by the "Try It" section in documentation

Comment: Finally, my comment works! I've been trying for some time with my own code

Answer (score 13):

How can you test a question w/out an answer?

Comment: Test comment... beep!

Comment: does this change the last update?

Comment: This comment was posted with version 2.1 of the API.

Comment: This is the second comment posted with, well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 8):

This is a test, for an API, sort-of.

Comment: I'd rather commit a quick fraudulent bounty transfer than flood the home page by bumping a bunch of questions with pointless minor suggested edits. I'm trying to give this account 20+ rep so it can test the MSE chat.

Comment: truly, this is *exemplary*

Comment: Wait, how can a bounty be awarded to a community wiki post?

Comment: @Stevoisiak Because somebody posted a bounty. They will lose that amount of rep when the bounty is started, but then of course the scheme to transfer those points to their sock puppet bot account didn't work because of the CW.

Comment: I stand corrected. Just now, I earned a bounty on a CW answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a dummy answer to test the API!

---

- [question comment #1](/posts/comments/1193261)
- [question comment #2](/posts/comments/1252368)
- [question comment #3](/posts/comments/1252595)

---

- [comment #1](/posts/comments/400717)
- [comment #2](/posts/comments/410169)
- [comment #3](/posts/comments/410773)

Comment: here is another dummy comment!

Comment: comment comment comment

Comment: another test comment

Answer (score 3):

Spec for Client with random 646713442; this is part of StackExchangeApiClient tests.

Answer (score 3):

## Heading 1

### Headign 2

#### Heading 3

Another API answer to test the might of Stack Exchange `code`

Code stuffs: hehe
~~,ml,mn~~

---

```js
alert('hehehe')
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<h1>Test snippet!</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Hello there</li>
</ul>
```

---

asdfa dfasd f
test

Other stuff

Answer (score 2):

**Another test answer for testing purposes**

Answer (score 2):

another test answer for me to test with? Test edit `/community`

Answer (score 2):

I guess I have to answer this to test my cool Android app.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

YET Another test answer for testing purposes

Answer (score 2):

### ?

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Lix Ok fine THIS ---> ‮҉ –  qwertynl 1 min ago

Comment: ever plan on revealing how you do that!?? :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - Are you talking about the actual post or the comment? :P

Comment: the comment :) I can see how you did the post!

Comment: Ok fine THIS ---> ‮҉ –  qwertynl 1 min ago

Comment: WAIT WHAT?? @Lix I DID IT!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - hehe... yes. There is a special unicode character in there (non printable so you don't see it) that mirrors/flips text.

Comment: cool! Thanks :) THAT IS COOL! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ There are lots of tools out there to do this kind of thing for you. For example: http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201211x1

Comment: thanks  for the link :) You can see my my username I like fiddling with these kinds of things :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ In that case you'll probably like this one: http://www.marlborotech.com/Zalgo.html
If you haven't already seen it around the site :) Specifically [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/558021)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - zero width characters is how my post here is only "one" character

Comment: yeah i've seen that - it took my ages to find out what it was tho! And yeah -  I though so :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ [se] is pretty tolerant of unicode shenanigans... but just don't abuse the power :P As you can see, comment sections can get pretty unruly.

Answer (score 2):

Spec for Client with random 780718851; this is part of StackExchangeApiClient tests.

Comment: Test **Comment** for Editing 2

Answer (score 2):

Spec for Client with random 409371460; this is part of StackExchangeApiClient tests.

Answer (score 2):

some more testing with this answer......

testing here: edit answer

asdasdas

Comment: FYI, the test answer ended up in the [Low Quality Posts review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/46752). Not sure if that was intended ...

Comment: @Glorfindel lol, no it wasn't! thanks for giving it the OK :)

Comment: [testsets](This is a test) testinininininin [Edit Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/51812/edit)

Comment: test: [Edit Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/51812/edit) comment

Comment: [edit answer](3) teststest

Comment: [edit answer](3) [asdasdas](dadasdas)

Answer (score 2):

This is a test of MathOverflow's new interface to Zentralblatt.

```js
// Run a search
function runSearch() {
    goBack();
    $('#popup-cite .search-spinner').removeSpinner().addSpinner();
    $.getJSON('https://zbmath.org/citationmatching/mathoverflow', { 'q': 'planar algebras' }, fetchCallback);
}

// Callback to run when search completes.
function fetchCallback(response) {
        
        var html = $('<div class="list">');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
            var result = response.results[i];
            var zbl = 'https://zbmath.org/?q=an:' + result.zbl_id;

            var link = result.links.length > 0 ? result.links[0] : '';
            var arxiv = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < result.links.length; j++) {
                     arxiv = result.links[j].includes("arxiv") ? result.links[j] : arxiv;
                }
            var authors = sanitizeForDisplay(result.authors);
            var title = sanitizeForDisplay(result.title);
            var citationHtml = sanitizeForDisplay(result.source);

            var result = $('<div class="item" style="float:none;padding:5px">')
                .html($('<div class = "summary post-link" style="float:none;width:auto;font-weight:bold;">')
                    .text(title))
                .append('<br/>')
                .append($('<span class="body-summary" style="float:none"></span>')
                    .append(authors + '<br/>' + citationHtml + '<br/> Preview (opens in new tab): ')
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(link, 'article'))
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(zbl, 'zbmath'))
                    .append(renderOptionalLink(arxiv, 'arxiv'))
                )
                .click(loadResultCallback(link, result))
                .hover(function () { $(this).css('background-color', '#e6e6e6') }, function () { $(this).css('background-color', '#fff') });

            html.append(result);
            result.find('a').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
        }
        $('#results').html('').append(html);
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'results']);
        $('#popup-cite .search-spinner').removeSpinner();
}

function getCitationHtml(json) {
  var arxiv = '';
  for (var j = 0; j < json.links.length; j++) {
    arxiv = json.links[j].includes("arxiv") ? json.links[j] : arxiv;
  }
  var cite = $('<cite>').attr('authors', json.authors)
          .append('_' + json.authors + '_, ')
          .append('[**' + json.title + '**](' + encodeURI(json.links.length > 0 ? json.links[0] : '') + '), ')
          .append(json.source + ' [ZBL' + json.zbl_id + '](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:' + json.zbl_id + ')')
          .append(arxiv ? ' [arXiv:' + arxiv.split('/').pop() + '](' + arxiv + ')' : '')
          .append('.');

  var citeContainer = $('<span></span>').append(cite).html();

  return citeContainer;
  }


// MathJax stub
var MathJax = {Hub: {Queue: function(arr) { }}};


// stubs
function sanitizeForDisplay(html) {
    return html;
}
 
function goBack() { }

function renderOptionalLink(href, text) {
    if (href) {
        return $(sanitizeForDisplay($('<a>').attr('href', href).text(text + ' ').prop('outerHTML'))).attr('target', '_blank');
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function loadResultCallback(link, result) {
  return function() {
    var html = getCitationHtml(result);
    $('#link').html('').append(html);
  }
}

$.fn.extend( { removeSpinner  : function() { return this; } });
$.fn.extend( { addSpinner  : function() { return this;} });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testcases">
  <button onclick="javascript:runSearch();">Search "planar algebras"</button>

</div>

<div id="results">
  No results yet.
</div>
<div id="link">
  No link yet.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: _______________|

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a test

Formatting:
`codeblock`,

[link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812),

**bold**

Big codeblock:

```js
console.log("codeblock works") // test comment in codeblock
```

Comment: This comment has been edited

Answer (score 0):

comes to his because spent 4 weeks says abstains murky buddy

Comment: comments are very bad

Comment: never been better

Answer (score 0):

Another test answer for testing purposes.

Now **Editing** a Old *Answer* to check from `API` If it **works**....

Comment: hi @ChuckBatson

Comment: hi there @ChuckTest

Comment: things are well here @ChuckTest thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

Just testing - body must be at least 30 characters

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Comments must be at least 15 characters, as you can see above.

Answer (score 0):

Spec for Client with random 1525546784; this is part of StackExchangeApiClient tests.

Answer (score 0):

Spec for Client with random 1314354391; this is part of StackExchangeApiClient tests.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can set 'DefaultSenderID'

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

s = boto3.Session(profile_name='Godzilla')
sns = s.client('sns')

sns.set_sms_attributes(
    attributes={
        'DefaultSenderID': 'Godzilla',

    }
)

response = sns.get_sms_attributes(
    attributes=[
        'DefaultSenderID',
    ]
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Test for comment. 
As workaround you can set 'DefaultSenderID'

<!-- language: lang-py -->

    #!/usr/bin/env python
    
    import boto3
    
    s = boto3.Session(profile_name='Godzilla')
    sns = s.client('sns')
    
    sns.set_sms_attributes(
        attributes={
            'DefaultSenderID': 'Godzilla',
    
        }
    )
    
    response = sns.get_sms_attributes(
        attributes=[
            'DefaultSenderID',
        ]
    )
    
    print(response)

Answer (score 0):

Hello World :) :)Testing answer API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Hello World :) :) Testing a sample comment

Answer (score 0):

Yet another test answer for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Hello World :) :) Testing a sample answer. Testing Editing answer now.

Update: Now I am testing Editing on Answers.

Update: 2nd Attempt

Update: 3rd Attempt

Update: 4th Attempt

Update: Final Attempt to Test Editing

Update: 2nd Final Attempt to Test Editing

```
NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
```

Done Testing. Last Testing. Navigation Back Final Testing.

**Update: Testing after long time to make sure app still works.**

Answer (score 0):

Test, please ignore it.

Blah, blah .. blah?

Answer (score 0):

Testing answer API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intentionally locked, should you need to test what happens if you try to vote on/edit/comment on a locked post.

Answer (score 0):

This is my dummy answer, containing a link to the [AspectJ 1.8.4 release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-184.html).

Another line was added.

Answer (score -1):

Just testing - body must be at least 30 characters

Comment: Are you sure about this? I am not sure  Are you sure about this? I am not sure Are you sure about this? I am not sure Are you sure about this? I am not sure Are you sure about this? I am not sure

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score -1):

there is no more, this is the end. goodbye.

Answer (score -1):

Going wild with dem dank memes:

[image: memes]:

yay...

[image: alt]

[image: alt]

updating answer 22222. sdfasd fasdf a

Comment: why the downvote? I'm trying to test the API here :D

Comment: Maybe someone is testing downvotes via the API... ;)

Comment: Lmao oh my God that somehow never occured to me! #dying

Answer (score -1):

Testing answer API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-answer)

Answer (score -1):

This is to test the answer from api

Comment: This is to test the comment from api

Comment: This is to test the comment from api

Answer (score -2):

This is to test the answer from api

Answer (score -2):

posting `sample` *answer* from api