# Complete exasperation with sending POST requests to StackOverflow

Tags: support, meta, http

I am trying to send a POST request to Meta using my account... but it's just not working very well. Using [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/), I was able to post [one comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox), but I have had no luck getting it to work with a PHP script.

I used a TCP monitor to capture the packets going back and forth between my browser and the server and managed to figure out some of it.

I am hoping someone on the team can help me here. Here is the POST request I'm sending:

```
POST /posts/51812/comments HTTP/1.1
Host: meta.stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/
Cookie: usr=*********; somusr=*********
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 87

comment=This+comment+was+posted+from+someplace...&fkey=********
```

As you can see, a normal request. I have a few questions though:

- What is the `fkey` parameter for? Where does it come from? What I have been doing thus far is fetching the page I want to post the comment on and using a RegEx to dig up the value.
- Why does the server return the following and what does it mean?

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/51812/comments
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 01:44:07 GMT
Content-Length: 171
...
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Weird... this post has a downvote but it's not showing up.

Comment: Usually that means it's a flag (flags don't cause the summary reputation to be recalculated), but I don't know what this would've been flagged for

Comment: If posting with netcat works but not with PHP, doesn't that mean your PHP code is wrong? ergo, belongs on SO.

Comment: @Ether: No, the PHP code is syntactically correct. It's just that the SO web servers are sending funny responses to my requests. I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 18):

This is by design. We don't want bots posting here, and I won't be providing any information to assist in the creation of said bots.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not making a bot. I'm trying to enhance [StackMobile](http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone) with write capabilities. Since there is no write-enabled API, I'm stuck using HTTP.

Comment: I think this is a good stance.  Wait for a version of the API if you need to be able to post anything programatically.

Comment: I've **almost** got it going... I managed to post a couple comments now and again in a highly controlled setup.

Comment: @George just wait until the read/write API gets released

Comment: @Justin, @Earlz: But I don't *want* to wait. You saw how long it took to get v1.0 out.

Comment: @george ok, but know that the entire team's day, every day, will be spent thinking up new ways to break you.

Comment: @Jeff: Don't worry, I'm ready to give up - the whole thing is so complicated. I've got shell windows, network traffic analyzers, scripts, and browser extensions all over my desktop. *Sigh.* I was hoping it would work.

Comment: Have (either of) you tried jQuery?

Comment: First users ask for a mobile interface. Jeff says, "Nah. But we'll provide an API so you can write your own!". Now that someone _actually did_ write one, the poor guy can't get support to make it post. Jeez!

Comment: @Andrew: ha ha ha! That won't help, of course.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you! I was beginning to think nobody cared that this won't work. I spent literally **hours** yesterday and the day before debugging HTTP requests, constructing a complex proxy, and banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Hi George.  I hacked together something that works (pending any changes in StackOverflow's URLs and webpage structure).  Here is the github: https://github.com/danchoi/ask_stack

My solution involves using SeleniumRC/Firefox as an intermediary between the command line tool and the StackOverflow server. This will let you post a question to StackOverflow from the unix command line.

By the way, my goal is not to faciliate spamming SO.  I had a problem, which is that I wanted to write my StackOverflow questions in Vim and post them from the command line, and I hacked a solution.

Comment: Hmmm... that's neat. I'll have to take a look at it.

Comment: btW the tool only posts questions right now, but the same approach should work for comments. There is also apparently a way to keep things clean and run Firefox in a kind of "headless" mode using Xvfb so it doesn't open two Firefox windows each time.