# Is there a way to post and edit questions on Stack Overflow from the command line?

Tags: feature-request, api, posting

I'm getting tired of using the web form to submit and edit questions on Stack Overflow. Is there a way to do this using the text editor of your choice and a command line tool? If not, is there an API that one can use to make such a tool?

Comment: What exactly is tiring you with the web form? Also, just to link as it is a similar kind of situation of not using the web form, but here's [a flat denial to allowing POST requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58444/complete-exasperation-with-sending-post-requests-to-stackoverflow).

Comment: I don't like web forms in general, especially for writing and posting content. I like the use the command line and vim when I can to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I hacked my own tool for this. It's only a proof of concept.  If anyone wants to try it and give me feedback, or even just encouragement, please do.  Long live the command line, especially here of all places.  https://github.com/danchoi/ask_stack

I hope StackOverflow implements a way to post question using OAuth or something. I don't think there is any good reason this should not be implemented. But in the meantime, the clunkier Selenium-based approach will have to do.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer. **No**

There is an API and you can read more about it at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com). However it is read only, and at this point there is no clear indication of when a write enable API will be available.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it, but there is a command line browser called [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) that might work on Stack Overflow.

If that doesn't work, then no, there is no way to ask or edit questions from the command line.

There is an API, that can be used to build command line apps for Stack Overflow, but it is currently read-only.

Check out the [read-only command line app](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu) if you are interested.