# Login using the Lynx browser

Tags: support, login, openid, browsers

How do you login to the sites if you are using a text-browser such as Lynx? I get the error

> Because JavaScript is disabled, you can only log in by entering your openID URL manually

When JavaScript is enabled, I click on the Google icon and it logs me in. But I do not know what an openID URL is. Could you please tell me what this means and how to log in?

Comment: I can view the pages with little problem, but i want to answer and ask questions and to do that i need to login.

Comment: `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: You have to love people that use lynx...

Comment: @rene: indeed, you should: they force you to write decent sites! :)

Comment: @Bart correct, just tried and it's working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what shocks me more, a Lynx user trying to use Stack Exchange, a Lynx user that does not understand the meaning of "...you can only log in by entering your openID URL manually..." or a Lynx user that has not been flamed to death by now by w3m users...

Comment: This reminds me, I need to open a question about how SO doesn't display properly on my TI-85 graphing calculator.

Comment: Lynx is such an amazing browser.

Comment: That is so cool, you can access the internet with your TI-85 graphing calculator, i would love to hear more.

Answer (score 2):

An **OpenID identifier** is a URL that represents an identity on the Internet. [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) was invented by LiveJournal as a way for users to prove their control over a particular blog. It has since come to be used by Google, AOL, Yahoo!, Stack Exchange, and other web sites as a decentralized authentication platform to let someone with an account on one site (the "provider") log in to other sites ("relying parties"). Sometimes the identifier is specific to a user, such as a user's profile page or blog, and sometimes it's a generic identifier that the provider redirects to a user's identifier. For more information about OpenID, check [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

As Bart pointed out in a comment to the question, Google is an OpenID provider. This generic identifier will trigger the Google Account login flow on Stack Exchange or any other relying party:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

In any case, there are good reasons to access Stack Exchange sites with Lynx or another user agent that does not require a running GUI, such as doing things that the Stack Exchange sites support but which currently do not have a corresponding API function. Posting questions and answers [used to be one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76693/is-there-a-way-to-post-and-edit-questions-on-stack-overflow-from-the-command-lin?lq=1) back in the first quarter of 2011 when the API was read-only. As of the fourth quarter of 2014, one thing that the API still does not support is [suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231766/not-allowed-to-suggest-edits-in-android-app).