# »Not allowed to suggest edits« in Android app

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

I just tried to edit a question (retag and new title) on Movies & TV via the SE Android app.

When I clicked on „Preview“ or „Submit“,  I got the pop-up message

> Not allowed to suggest edits

This was reproducible with another question.

Interestingly enough, clicking the submit button a second time worked and my edit was accepted.

Needless to say, I have edit privileges. So I should be able to not only suggest edits, but edit instantly.

Comment: Suggesting edits is not built into the API yet, so it won't work on the android and iOS apps.

Comment: I did not try to suggest an edit, but make one (without suggesting). I have edit privilege.

Comment: And, as I said, it worked when I ignored the strange message and clicked the button again.