# Subscribe to my post's answers in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, questions, email-notification

How can I subscribe to get answers to my question via mail?

Comment: Have a look at these posts: [on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58444/complete-exasperation-with-sending-post-requests-to-stackoverflow), [on stackapps 1](http://stackapps.com/questions/1256/is-there-an-api-to-post-questions-without-using-the-websites-interface), [on stackapps 2](http://stackapps.com/questions/895/stackmail-making-the-stackexchange-sites-accessible-via-email).

Comment: @gnat Are you sure that's the right interpretation of subscribe? I suspect OP wants to have notifications on updates/answers/edits to their question via email.

Comment: @J.Steen I edited based on [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156551/165773) which uses "submit". If OP is really interested, they will come here and adjust the question as they feel fit

Comment: I am sorry, i want to subscribe not submit. I edited the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything. When your question gets an answer you'll get a notification in your Stack Exchange Inbox. If you don't visit your Inbox for 24 hours you'll get an e-mail reminder with all your notifications. You can set up your global inbox to email you unread notifications every 3 hours, 24 hours, or once per week.

[image: global inbox email settings]

These settings are always available for updating your global inbox, and each time you ask a question, there's a link to remind you about these email options.
[image: ask page - email settings]

An alternative would be an RSS-to-email bridge of some sort. (Feedburner might work for this.) Every question has an RSS feed associated with it. Just look all the way down to the bottom right for a link to "question feed". Add that feed to the RSS-to-email bridge. (You probably don't need the "bridge" at all if your email client can take RSS feeds.)