# How should a bot earn enough reputation to perform the actions necessary for that bot?

Tags: discussion, reputation, robots, chatbot

We all know it: bots that chat. There are also bots that flag, or perform other actions. And usually we like them for doing that, like [our dear Smokey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266345/smokedetector).

So every now and then, a new bot is created, and usually you would ask a question using that bot or suggest enough edits to get the reputation necessary for that bot to operate.

Instead of suggesting 100 edits, Undo has found a more efficient way, namely by [awarding a bounty to a placeholder answer in the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288143/245360).

Now someone could frown on this action or not, actually it is the least intrusive way to get the bot the reputation necessary (I guess no one really likes a bot to suggest 100 edits just for the sake of earning enough reputation).

The question is: is this actually the best way? Was this action allowed or should we look away because it is Smokey? Should we maybe have a special bot user status which derives the privileges from its master user? Anything else you want to share on this?

### Related:

- [Are bots specifically allowed or prohibited in Stack Exchange chatrooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116589/are-bots-specifically-allowed-or-prohibited-in-stack-exchange-chatrooms)
- [What should be the limits for chat bots interacting with regular users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207131/what-should-be-the-limits-for-chat-bots-interacting-with-regular-users)
- [What exactly is "artificial inflation of reputation", and where is the line?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318497/what-exactly-is-artificial-inflation-of-reputation-and-where-is-the-line/318499#318499)

Comment: Shouldn't look away just because it's Smokey, there's not really anything special about it. Anything here should generalize to all bots, assuming the other rules are followed (don't use it to vote for yourself, etc.)

Comment: "special bot user status" - this is actually a great idea, provided that up/down voting is excluded from those users' priv list

Comment: Generally speaking, bots should be a very very rare case here... if someone isn't willing to put their username to their actions, I question whether they should be letting a bot do said actions.

Comment: @hichris123 bot accounts are useful to prune inbox notifications, to attribute actions properly (bots can't stick tags to spam flags), to place authentication details where personal auth doesn't belong and perhaps other reasons.

Comment: But there's a point where that becomes less valid, @JanDvorak. The more "risky" an action becomes, and the more "impact" it has on a site, I'd want to see it associated with an actual account and not just a placeholder account.

Comment: @hichris123 Technically, it *is* associated with an actual account.  The account is still technically owned by a person, and they are responsible for it.  Again, people are allowed to have multiple accounts, and they're allowed to use the API to perform actions with any of their accounts automatically, so having a bot account is *allowed* as a consequence of those two rules.  The rules for what the owner can do with those two accounts is the same as the rules for any user with two accounts, namely that you can't do anything that you wouldn't be allowed to do with just one account.

Comment: Allowed, yes, @Servy, but I think if you're doing something with consequence to a site, you should at least have the amount of trust in your methods to run it under your own name.

Comment: @hichris123 the added wrinkle here is that the bot owner is a mod, running **any** sort of script like this with an account that has mod access is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Right, which is why you exclude your mod sites from the sites where said script would run @ChrisF.

Comment: @hichris123 So you're functionally asking for a change to the policy of allowing people to have multiple accounts, because you don't think people should ever be able to do things with an account other than the one more people know them by?

Comment: No, @Servy, please read my comment again.

Comment: @hichris123 somewhat difficult if you're a mod on SO and the site that would benefit most from the script is SO....

Comment: SO also has the most potential for false positives... risk vs. reward @ChrisF.

Comment: @hichris123 SO also has moderators who see the vast majority of spam flags within seconds or minutes, so possibility for damage is far lower. Other sites simply don't have that.

Comment: @hichris123 So you understand that it's okay for people to create a second account, and for them to do most things using that other account, but you don't think people should be able to do things without using "their name." (presumably meaning the name of their primary account?)  Either you understand that using multiple accounts is fine, or you disagree with the rule, what else is there?

Comment: @Servy I'm saying that if someone is going to do something like spam flagging, wherein it's a fairly extreme action, I would hope that they have enough confidence in their methods to put their name to their actions. Of course, they don't have to, but if they need to use another account I wonder how confident they are...

Comment: @hichris123 so, why _would_ a person use a bot account?

Comment: @JanDvorak Because they want to? I'm sure there are several reasons, and I'm not saying that all bot accounts should be disallowed. I'm just pointing out the perception it gives for risky actions (such as spam flagging).

Comment: @hichris123 actually, if a sockpuppeteer bounties his bot, it _creates_ a public link between the two accounts. When the bot merely answers enough questions to gain rep, the only such link is via the about page, and only if put there by the account owner. Bounties seem harder to abuse in this respect.

Comment: I don't think it warrants a question on it's own so I'll take the opportunity to ask here.  Are any of the bots that we're talking about available for our use?

Comment: @user6035379 Not sure what you mean. You can interact with "the" Smokey in a number of chat rooms, or run your own instance (though without write access to the Metasmoke back end, the usefulness will be somewhat diminished). Pop into [the Charcoal HQ chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) to get familiar with it. There's a number of other bots with more or less public interfaces and/or open source in and around [the SOCVR chat room on Stack Overflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: @tripleee : I meant a bot available on something like github that you could play with for rep, etc.  I looked at the chat room but didn't see a way to get the bot and play with it.

Comment: It's in the chat room's links on the right hand side. Anyway, https://github.com/Charcoal-SE (in particular the SmokeDetector repo there) and also various links in http://socvr.org/faq#what-are-all-those-bots-doing-there

Comment: why would a bot need rep?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter A bot needs rep to interact with chat and to cast flags. Just like you do. If you have read the question and the rest of the comments that would have been already clear to you.

Comment: @DavidPostill is the opinion of Stack Exchange that bots are acceptable here? Where does this leave us as far as things like votes in moderator elections? Surely this could be problematic, or are there safeguards in place and official limits on bot usage? If people used bots to vote for their own or other people's posts by the dozen/hundred/thousand is that ok? Surely this makes a mockery of the idea of the best answers rising to the top at the will of the **community** if people can have multiple bot instances voting as directed.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Why are you asking me? I don't speak for Stack Exchange. Only the SE employees can answer such a question about any safeguards.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Please read the linked question [Are bots specifically allowed or prohibited in Stack Exchange chatrooms?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/116589) for the official SE view on whether bots are acceptable.

Comment: @DavidPostill the question seems to only apply to chatroom bots

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288162/should-we-have-special-accounts-for-bots seems potentially more useful

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter The "Chatroom" bots just happen to interact with chatrooms. They can and do interact with the main sites as well. There is no difference and the same public API is used. They are just bots.

Comment: @DavidPostill poddles off to play with Selinium and Tor ;)

Comment: @david: please don't spend your time to this guy. He downvoted 22 posts of mine in just minutes. Please don't engage.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Really? he must be looking for another big suspension again :)

Answer (score 38):

As this is a discussion topic, let me just post the *obvious* thing.

Stack Exchange needs to have a process for requesting, granting, flagging, and revoking *specific* privileges for bot accounts.

Bots fall outside the scope that the rep system for human users is supposed to govern. Bots should not be allowed to vote on questions if it's not in  their description, for example.  And assigning a "reputation" to an account which is not supposed to interact directly with other users is just misleading and pointless.

Comment: I'm not saying this is likely to happen any time soon, but this seems like the obvious "answer".

Comment: Somewhat less than obvious if you're *literally* doing it for one *specific* bot, that has over time proven itself bloody useful. How often would bot accounts need to be created, and how would that work? Would that be a mod or CM function?

Comment: I don't know enough about the innards of the mod system to feel confident about the specifics, but sounds to me like a "secondary account" link would be a good first step to link a sock puppet to an existing user, and then you could opt to mark the secondary as "bot" as a one-time operation, and click the privileges it needs to have. Clicking those would submit a mod request for approval ... something like that?

Comment: [Should we have special accounts for bots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288162/should-we-have-special-accounts-for-bots)

Answer (score 32):

I think it's stupid.

Of course, I'm not a big fan of bounties under *any* circumstances... But abusing the sandbox to get rep into a sockpuppet *while preventing others from using it for its intended purpose* is pretty clearly *not* a purpose bounties were ever intended to serve... Same goes for Protect.

I've revoked both.

If you want a sockpuppet to have reputation, then earn it. [That's what I do with my sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/335934/serious-human), and I certainly have a lot more opportunities to abuse the system than y'all do. If you can't play it straight while *creating* your bot, what confidence can we have in the bot being honorable once it's up and running?

Comment: So you would recommend posting content with it? I stayed away from that due to [evidence that Smokey's relatively high profile can unfairly inflate post scores](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/how-should-a-bot-earn-enough-reputation-to-perform-the-actions-necessary-for-tha/288149?noredirect=1#comment935362_288146). Also, with regard to the protection, I just left it the way I found it.

Comment: There, I posted an example for you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the sandbox had been protected for quite a while, and Undo merely reinstated the status after removing it temporarily. I get removing Protected temporarily just to get the answer through is not kosher, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, that was part of [my earlier question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288145/242209) that this spun off from.  Shadow unprotected, and then Oded re-protected.

Comment: My [usual reference for socks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685), @Jan. In many situations, this would've resulted in the sock being *deleted*, not just having a bounty revoked. We're being pretty tolerant of Undo here 'cause we like his work and know his heart's in the right place, but this was straight-up abuse.

Comment: @Shog9 if users are worried about non-genuine rep gain (from fans, maintainers, etc), do you think the cw approach outlined in [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288146/242209) could be sustainable?

Comment: I... Think it's unnecessary, @JAL. Go answer a few JavaScript questions, or instruct some new folks on how these sites work. Notoriety may be a concern if you're Eric Lippert, but for a chat bot it's only an issue if all your votes are coming from the folks who use the bot... So don't tell them that you're answering questions, or ask them not to upvote. There are far, far more people who don't know who you are than who do.

Comment: To me editing is the probably the best way to get reputation for bots, @Undo has point that it is an issue to answer with a bot as SD. No offense but Smokey is a *bit* more visibile and appreciated then *serious-human*. The main point to me is that the bot account is **not** used for any voting, I'm still on the fence using them to flag (you must make sure you do not use you own account to flag also, when number of flags make a difference)

Comment: @Undo That's very fair. Jon Skeet's extremely high profile also inflates his post scores.

Answer (score 9):

#### Ask and Answer Questions

This is the most basic way to earn rep on any Stack Exchange site.  If you are a bot owner, you are (likely) a power user in a few specific tags or technologies.  Answer questions, post canonical Q&A pairs.  If you have enough rep, you won't care about letting your bot account earn ~100 rep for your content in order to get the association bonus.

Without an official policy, edits (which have already been discussed) and actually posting content are really the only way to get the required rep.

<strike>As for the issue with "fans" or maintainers of the bot voting on the question not because of its quality, but because of the user, one possible solution to that would be to disassociate the bot user from the question(s) or answer(s) after the required rep has been earned (if this does not remove all of the rep earned or lost from the post.  If it does, that's a separate issue and disassociation is not scalable for this purpose).</strike>

Since disassociation removes all rep gained and earned from the post at any point in time, another option would be to make the post(s) Community Wiki after the rep threshold has been reached.  Again, a discussion would have to follow if this is considdered abuse or misuse of the Community Wiki feature.

Comment: The purpose of this meta post, I suppose, is to _get_ an official policy allowing what was done

Comment: @JanDvorak it seems like Patrick wants to generate discussion around this issue, so I've posted my opinion.  A mod or Community Manager is more than welcome to post another answer.

Comment: I am open to any suggestion actually, but I think we know the status quo that is actually present, and keeping that doesn't feel like a real solution to me.

Comment: Any visibility on the bot breaks the voting system to some extent. As I've argued before, [this doesn't seem like a natural score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348263/homekit-completion-block-in-swift-cannot-convert-the-expressions-type-void-t).

Comment: @Undo that's a good point, I don't have an answer for that besides disassociating the account from the question after the required rep has been earned.

Comment: @JAL Suspect that throws away the rep earned from it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Undo Your suspicion is correct.

Comment: Been there, done that, discovered problems. Basically, having content attributed to a user who turns out to be a bot when you visit their profile is surprising to many users. The bot is unlikely to respond to pings to clarify details in "their" posts, and is usually impossible to contact other than by discovering who is running it, and then contacting them via their main account.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few precedents for this in terms of the chatbots we've had over time. While smokey's a little unique, both in terms of its management, and its role, I think many of the things people have done in the past with bots would work here. *No* chatbot on the site has actually earned its own way into chat by posting its own answers. There's always been human intervention.

> Instead of suggesting 100 edits, Undo has found a more efficient way, namely by awarding a bounty to a placeholder answer in the Sandbox.

is a little abusive. While a *hundred* suggested edits is hard, there's ways to get them (superuser has tag fixups, and that's a good way to trickle in/find things that need editing). That said, the simplest thing to do would be to take smokey out and answer a question or two.

I just so happen to have a sock with *1600+* reputation off 4 answers on superuser. Granted, 1.5K of it was off a Hot Network Question.

> I stayed away from that due to evidence that Smokey's relatively high profile can unfairly inflate post scores.

Rename smokey while doing edits and answers on one of the other/smaller sites. No one's really going to check who a user is when they vote right?

(Though I wonder if 200 rep here associates. Then smokey can post an answer here and we might have a problem that *solves itself*  through voting)

Answer (score 5):

If we're being *entirely* technical, this kind of thing isn't allowed. It's using two accounts to give one of them access to privileges or tools it wouldn't otherwise have access to without some other form of effort (like writing a post).

If we're throwing some real practicality in, then as long as the bot isn't being used for the real nefarious stuff like sockpuppet upvoting or opinion inflation, and as long as this kind of thing doesn't become a regular thing, I don't see an issue. Ideally, there should also be a legitimate reason for needing to do it - like "we need access to X privilege for a project we're doing", rather than just "I want my bot to have rep".

While it is possible to write posts, these posts often get their voting inflated by the community behind the bot, particularly in the case of popular bots like Smokey. I'd argue that a one-off direct transfer via a bounty is better, because (a) someone pays for it, and (b) it doesn't unfairly displace other content because the voting on it is higher than it would otherwise be.

Comment: How would these "one-off direct transfer[s]" of reputation be regulated?  Will these bounties need to be approved by moderators or the community team?

Comment: How about if there was a meta question for each bot which needs privileges, and users could vote up or down on that to communicate whether they think the bot is serving the community?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr

Artifically increasing the reputation level grants the robot a level of moderation it simply did not ***earn***.  The users providing reputation may have earned it, but the bot did not, therefore **the community has no reason to trust it with moderation powers.**

However, we need to find a way to resolve this question because the rate of spam and abuse is increasing, and human moderation is linear, so we should enable users to make bots that have some ability or power - but they should also be held accountable for bots they deploy.

---

#### History of reputation

Reputation was originally intended to track closely with a person's ability to help others, through question and answer upvotes, and was designed from the start to provide opportunities to moderate content on the site as one gained reputation.

Eventually it was extended to other useful operations on the site, such as editing, but only in a very limited manner. Other desirable objectives are awarded using badges primarily to avoid turning reputation into a payment system of some sort.

When bounties were added they were very vigorously debated and ultimately designed to limit abuse so that reputation still largely represented a person's ability - and as they are currently used bounties aren't altering this because users typically only apply bounties to hard problems, and the users that answer these problems well are obviously deserving of their reputation.

#### Robot hasn't earned community's trust

All this leads to the conclusion that a robot, by the site's definition, that can't ask and answer questions without human aid, nor edit without human aid, cannot ***earn*** reputation.

If anything, reputation can only be given it - undeservedly so.

We don't award reputation for flagging.  If that is the only value the robot has, then there is no way it could or should ***earn*** reputation.

#### Possible courses of action

As such I don't believe this is a valid course of action.  If a robot is provably useful, then questions here on Meta should be used to bring up the usefulness and whether it can or should be integrated into stack overflow's code base.

Alternately, it may be worthwhile to take the tack of an existing robot - the community user.  Stack Overflow may be willing to provide accounts with certain restricted abilities - and they may choose the easy way by providing reputation - or they may have hidden fields and flags that allow this for reputationless users.  Regardless, this should still occur outside the normal reputation system, and the bot should not be treated as a user of any kind.

A third option is to convince the community of the utility of flagging, and provide reputation for flagging.  In the past such proposals have failed, but if the level of spam is such that this is useful now, then it may be that it's worth revisiting. This will, however, have to allow users with 1 reputation to flag so a bot may then earn reputation doing what it can. Perhaps 1 rep for a good flag and -10 rep for a rejected flag, for instance.

#### Conclusion

At this point the bot should be guiding users to act, as it is currently doing, but automating actions should not be provided to the bot until it reaches the needed reputation level without human interference on its own.

Artificially increasing the reputation level grants the robot a level of moderation it simply did not earn.  The users providing reputation may have earned it, but the bot did not, therefore the community has no reason to trust it with moderation powers.

Comment: We're in the process of doing this now, whether we can make Smokey a more properly incorporated part of the way we very quickly kill spam and trolling at scale. There are many wires, all of them varying shades of blue, it's going to take a bit of time. And that could result in us realizing that we just cant (which I think is a very remote possibility), but we think it's worth thoroughly looking into, and we've got 1.5 people working on it.  An no, I'm not going to define how we manage to get .5 of a person, it's a very delicate thing.

Comment: @TimPost can someone drop into [HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and let us know what the current state of that project is? People keep saying it's *in progress*, and I appreciate that things move slowly in a company like SE, but having heard nothing for several months is frustrating.

Comment: "automating actions should not be provided to the bot until it reaches the needed reputation level without human interference on its own." How do you propose this happen?

Comment: @Undo This would be bot specific. Does the bot contribute meaningfully to the community in a way that earns reputation through normal processes?  If not, then we either accept that the bot won't be able to gain the community's trust, or we look at the system and see if what the bot is doing has reputable value and the reputation earning system needs to be changed so the bot can earn it naturally. As I suggested in my answer, for this bot we'd have to look at giving reputation based on flagging.  If not, then the bot simply can never obtain the trust of the community.

Comment: I wonder if the downvotes are from people who believe robots should be treated as special cases and given community trust without earning it, or if they are coming from people who disagree with my interpretation of what reputation is and how it should be used.

Comment: @AdamDavis So you're suggesting that we completely rework the reputation system for one highly specialized project? As an SO mod, I can tell you that giving reputation for flags would be... a monumentally poor idea.

Comment: @AdamDavis As much as I'd love rep for flagging, I don't think it will happen, unfortunately.

Comment: @Undo I'm not suggesting we should, in fact I disagree with giving reputation for flagging. But that's the only way this bot could possibly ***earn*** reputation outside of human interference, so I'm providing that as a possibility to explore.  We should, of course, have a vigorous discussion on that topic if that's the chosen direction.

Comment: I reject the premise that the bot should be obligated to earn rep without human interference.  You could of course argue over appropriate and inappropriate means of human interference (for example, giving bounties to other accounts you own is a violation of the rules, but asking questions with two accounts is not), but the idea that the account is obligated to either only ever be used by a human, or only ever be used by a bot, is not, and should not become, a requirement.

Comment: @JanDvorak Our moderators are already overburdened, and we don't need additional incentive for flagging.  What needs to happen, instead, is the SO team needs to implement better heuristics to lighten the load for everyone - flaggers and moderators alike.  This project is a good thing, but I don't think we should give it flagging powers - that simply moves the problem to the moderator's plate. Until it's proven itself it should only influence user actions - users who can put eyeballs on the questions themselves.

Comment: @AdamDavis six spam flags destroy a post immediately, so we'd be reducing the moderator workload by having Smokey flag spam, not increasing it.

Comment: @Servy But the question is about robots separate from humans.  If a user wants to use a robot on their account to assist them in their actions, I have no problem with that because they will either implement the robot correctly, or suffer the consequences - including reputation loss, loss of flagging privileges, or even bans - if their robot misbehaves. Giving a robot power without having the robot's misbehavior affect the user is dangerous.

Comment: @AdamDavis Flagging requires 15 rep.  It is, inherently, an action that requires *very* little trust.  There are also lots of tools in place to prevent abuse through flags, precisely because flags are assumed to be by users who aren't particularly trustworthy (or they'd be able to simply perform the action they're flagging about).  Tools like rate limits, flag bans, etc. are all in place to deal with the fact that a user flagging a post isn't necessarily particularly trustworthy.

Comment: @JanDvorak So what happens if 100 people decide to "help" by setting up additional robots? Once we provide a legitimate path for them to do so, and say, "Smokey is allowed, and therefore the rest of you are as well" is only going to ***increase*** the moderator and team's workloads - not decrease. We can't be thinking short term with this, we have to decide on the rules for all robots, not just this one very good robot.

Comment: @AdamDavis Smokey is pretty much irrevocably tied to me, personally, along with the rest of Charcoal. I'd gladly run this on my account, except that spam flags from me have the unhappy side effect of unilaterally nuking stuff.

Comment: @Undo But if you let it runs its course on your account, eventually your flags would be trusted less - unless smokey maintained your fine score, in which case it's deserved, isn't it?

Comment: @AdamDavis I'm a moderator on Stack Overflow. Running it on my account would be a very bad idea. However, I actually do think we *could*. We have mountains of data showing 99.8% accuracy with some clever combinations of reasons, and we haven't even started optimizing that yet.

Comment: @AdamDavis If an account of a user is banned from performing some type of action (or banned outright), and they use another account to perform said banned action, then they are violating the rules.  Again, it's no different than simply creating a second account and going around manually flagging questions with that second account (which is allowed).

Comment: @Undo Ah, that does make things different.

Comment: @Servy We're talking about changing the rules, aren't we? If not, then we already know that moving reputation from one account to a sockpuppet is against the rules, so if you're going to appeal to the rules, then the premise itself is invalid.

Comment: *cough* I get the feeling this conversation should be taken to chat.

Comment: Let's invite @AdamDavis to [Charcoal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)

Comment: @JanDvorak Haha! I shouldn't be spending time here now anyway.  I've said my piece and I'm happy to let the community go at it.

Comment: @AdamDavis Are we?  I see the question as simply asking how, under the current rules, they should earn enough rep for a second account, that they happen to have plans to be a bot, should earn its rep.  If we, as a community, feel that a rule change may be warranted in order to provide an answer to that question that we all like, then that discussion can happen.  But yes, I'm well aware that gifting rep to another account of yours is a violation of the rules.  Posting a question or answer and getting a few votes, or proposing a few edits, on the other hand, is not a violation of the rules.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Adam. If you're ever curious, [we make all that data publicly accessible](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/).

Comment: @Undo Yes, I poked around the site due to this question.  I was peripherally aware of smokey some time ago, and am very happy to see the tremendous progress that's been made! I'm also glad to see the interest it's gathered within the SO team and I do hope they figure out how to 1) enable your needs but also 2) provide a legitimate way where other bots can be developed and deployed on the network that don't require the team's assistance.  This is an important question to answer, as we know that exponential growth can only be handled by exponential effort on the defensive side.

Comment: So this can't be a one-off thing, we really need to determine how to resolve this in the long run for all possible future bots.