# Navigation to next/prev post via buttons is broken

Tags: bug, ios-app, scrolling

Navigation using up/down arrows in the top right corner of the iOS app is broken (only for portrait mode).

Tested on this post: [How should a bot earn enough reputation to perform the actions necessary for that bot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288144/339911)

After opening question, first tap on "down" scrolls to the 1st answer, but title contains "Answer 2 of 6".
Second and next taps on "down" show correct titles and positioning (most of times, sometimes with the same issue as for the 1st answer).

"Answer 1 of 6" quickly displays while scrolling via buttons. Scrolling via swipe by finger shows title as expected.

I think you need to change Y start position for the 1st answer to fix this issue.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Works as expected for me (just noticed you're on iPad.. works ok for me on iPhone anyway)

Comment: Fine for me on iPhone 5s too.