# Is it allowed to review others' suggested edits to make space in the edit queue for your alternate account to make suggested edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, user-accounts

I wanted to create a new account on Stack Overflow to be a chat bot in their chat server, but to chat, an account would need at least 20 rep. So I started to make edits, but the edit queue kept getting full. Would it be wrong for me to review **other users'** edits just so that there's enough space in the edit queue for my alternate account to make edits?

**Just to clarify, I'm not saying to review my own edits, just review other people's edits to make room in the queue for other people to review mine.**

[How should a bot earn enough reputation to perform the actions necessary for that bot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/how-should-a-bot-earn-enough-reputation-to-perform-the-actions-necessary-for-tha) doesn't answer my question because it does not address reviewing edits of **other people** to make room in the edit queue for my edits.

[How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) doesn't answer my question because it's about a socket puppet that is used for deception. I was just trying to make a small bot on the chat server for chit chat.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about *"... I wanted to create a new account on Stack Overflow to be a chat bot in their chat server..."*

Comment: Basically grinding edits to get 20 reputation to be able to chat, then hooking up a chatbot to that.

Comment: @AugustoVasques an account needs 20 reps to be able to send messages on chat. There are also 3 chat servers: SO, SE, and MSE. The SO chat server only counts reps on SO, the MSE chat server only counts reps on MSE, though the SE chat server counts reps from all accounts.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. maybe "to be a chat bot in their chat server" in English does not have the same meaning as in Portuguese(my native language). For me it means installing an advertisement robot in the chat server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should a bot earn enough reputation to perform the actions necessary for that bot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288144/how-should-a-bot-earn-enough-reputation-to-perform-the-actions-necessary-for-tha)

Comment: See also [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: In brief, reviewing the queue on your main account is fine as long as you don't review suggested edits by your sock puppet account.

Comment: You'd have to have at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits. Is _this_ not your main account?

Comment: I don't like the proposed duplicate, I think this answers your question better: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). A bot account is just a special kind of socket-puppet account, and all the same rules about avoiding cross-activity apply. Reviewing edits doesn't directly benefit your bot in an unfair way that isn't available to others, so it's just fine. The line to avoid is what you've already called out: always skip your sock account's suggested edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the reviews you're making are legit, it's not wrong, the reason why people review are totally not relevant. Some may do it due to being bored, some do it for the badges, and some, well, might do that to make room for their bots. All of those are fine.

---

That said, there is a reason why the queue is full these days (well, more than before at least), which is the moderation strike. If you support that strike maybe better wait with the bot and reviews for a while. (Saying that just in case you didn't make the connection between strike and full queue. I do not encourage people to take either side, that's 100% the choice of every person to make.)

Comment: I seem to recall its *always* full, even pre-strike. I suspect other approaches might have more value.

Comment: @Journeyman what approaches? To encourage reviews? Probably, but that's not the question here.

Comment: to farm rep via edits.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike It wasn’t always full before the strike. It just often filled up, then got cleared more often. So while it would be full at multiple times each day, there was always room throughout the day (sometimes had to wait 1-2 days) to suggest new edits.

Comment: Still isn't conducive to farming rep via edits

Comment: @Journeyman I disagree. Edits are valid way to get reputation, it's not farming unless of course it's bunch of minor edits, but that should be rejected by reviewers.

Comment: Its deeply *inefficient* in this context.

Comment: @Journeyman perhaps, but still not wrong, and that's the purpose of the question here.

Comment: The Suggested Edits review queue being full has been a chronic problem on SO for years. I expect that it's worse now due to the strike, but it has been a problem since the topbar was redesigned to remove the badge on the reviews icon that showed how many suggested edit reviews were pending. The "red dot" that's now used is **much easier to ignore** than a badge with a number. It got even worse with the most "recent" revamp to the review queues that made reviewing more work (some of the changes were *really good*, but overall, the UI became harder to use).

Comment: @Makyen while I agree and annoyed at the topbar change, like Andreas said before, the queue was not always full before the strike, it did get much worse, which is expected. In the few times I checked the queue on SO in recent years, it was not full. (randomly, not following any bug report)

Comment: My experence is the opposite. When I needed to got one of my chat bot accounts enough rep to talk in chat, Stack Overflow was one of the worst sites to try to get rep, precisely because the queue was full so often.