# Would it be a good idea to have a test site for the API?

Tags: discussion, api

I'm working on a little chatbot (no spam!) that I would like to be able to read questions and answers and possibly comment if there is an easily detectable duplicate.

To avoid accidental spamming with comments of the main site, is there a test site that I could use to do this?

Also, if there is not, should I make that a proposal on Area 51?

Comment: You welcome to test this on the [API sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox) and/or the [regular sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) here.

Comment: There was an area 51 proposal for a sandbox site but it was closed after a while. It's been deleted now but I think the reason was too little interest and it would be more effort than it was worth it