# Is there a sandbox for the API where I can post questions?

Tags: support, questions, api

Is there a sandbox site for the Stack Exchange API?

I have found a couple of questions which were made for testing answers (EG [The API Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox)), but no way to test posting or editing questions.

Comment: Upvote [the Feature request](http://stackapps.com/questions/364/can-we-get-a-sandbox-please), which this question is a cross-site duplicate of.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no Sandbox for posting questions. You could suggest a Sandbox site (to allow all sort of actions through the API), but I am not sure if that will ever get there.

Answers are pretty useful anyways. Compared to questions they are not that different, so a good chance you get it working from coding answers only.

Comment: There have been a couple of 'Sandbox' attempts on Area 51, which were all closed. [This](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106283/sandbox) was the latest attempt.