# Can I send myself an inbox notification?

Tags: support, global-inbox, api, scripts

For developing apps and userscripts that deal with inbox notifications, it's often useful to get a notification for testing.

Is there any action I can take that will give myself an inbox notification? Asking others to leave comments and such works but is rather cumbersome (and probably a little annoying).

Comment: I _think_ pinging yourself in chat and leaving the room should work (especially if the quick chat notifications are enabled)

Comment: @Gerry Wait. Quick chat notifications?

Comment: Your chat profile -> prefs tab

Comment: Agree with @Gerry, self chat pings in some sandbox room should be better than using sock account for this.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work, it's not the best but at least it's controllable. It's all I've discovered so far:

1. Make a [sock puppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/230261) account (an incognito tab or a separate browser can be used).
2. Use it to make a post in one of the sandboxes ([Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/230261), [The API Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51812/230261)). The sock can comment on this post regardless of reputation (can always comment on own posts).
3. Leave a comment on that post with your main account, to make yourself pingable.
4. Ping your main account from the sock account on the comment thread to send a notification.
5. Delete the post when you're done so as to keep things tidy.

There's no good (and non-sketchy) way to test reputation notifications but the inbox notifications are at least useful.

It would be cool if there was an API call or something to send yourself test notifications.

Comment: Any reason you can't just "mock" the notification for testing?

Comment: @JonClements I'm reverse engineering some SE websockets / topbar-related stuff, so unfortunately mocking it sort of skips over the tricky part that I need to test.

Comment: Ahhh. As soon as I'd commented I'd thought that may well be the case :-)

Comment: @JonClements This: [Top Bar for Chat Rooms](https://stackapps.com/q/7404/25350)