# The "An edit has been made to a post" button is not working properly

Tags: bug, edits

Usually, whenever you click the button saying the post has been edited, it should show you the edited version. It seems to have an error, and does not show the edited version.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Be looking at post
2. Have the post be edited
3. Click the button saying the post was edited

This does not show the edited version of the post, but it does remove the banner. You have to refresh the page to see the edited version.

In the developer console, there is this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"Html":"            \r\n\r\n  \r\n<a name=\"375857\"></a>\r\n<div id=\"answer-375857\" class=\"answer js-answer\" data-answerid=\"375857\" data-score=\"0\" data-position-on-page=\"0\" data-highest-scored=\"0\" data-question-has-accepted-highest-score=\"0\"  itemprop=\"suggestedAnswer\" itemscope itemtype=\"https://schema.org/Answer\">\r\n    <div class=\"post-layout\">\r\n        <div class=\"votecell post-layout--left\">\r\n            <div class=\"js-voting-container d-flex jc-center fd-column ai-stretch gs4 fc-black-200\" data-post-id=\"375857\">\r\n        <button class=\"js-vote-up-btn flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer \"\r\n                data-controller=\"s-tooltip\"\r\n                data-s-tooltip-placement=\"right\"\r\n                title=\"This answer is useful\"\r\n                aria-pressed=\"false\"\r\n                aria-label=\"Up vote\"\r\n                data-selected-classes=\"fc-theme-primary\"\r\n                data-unselected-classes=\"\">\r\n            <svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"svg-icon iconArrowUpLg\" width=\"36\" height=\"36\" viewBox=\"0 0 36 36\"><path d=\"M2 25h32L18 9 2 25Z\"/></svg>\r\n        </button>\r\n        <div class=\"js-vote-count flex--item d-flex fd-column ai-center fc-black-500 fs-title\"\r\n             itemprop=\"upvoteCount\"\r\n             data-value=\"0\">\r\n            0\r\n        </div>\r\n        <button class=\"js-vote-down-btn flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer \"\r\n                data-controller=\"s-tooltip\"\r\n                data-s-tooltip-placement=\"right\"\r\n                title=\"This answer is not useful\"\r\n                aria-pressed=\"false\"\r\n                aria-label=\"Down vote\"\r\n                data-selected-classes=\"fc-theme-primary\"\r\n                data-unselected-classes=\"\">\r\n            <svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"svg-icon iconArrowDownLg\" width=\"36\" height=\"36\" viewBox=\"0 0 36 36\"><path d=\"M2 11h32L18 27 2 11Z\"/></svg>\r\n        </button>\r\n\r\n    \r\n            <div class=\"js-accepted-answer-indicator flex--item fc-green-500 py6 mtn8 d-none\" data-s-tooltip-placement=\"right\" title=\"Loading when this answer was accepted&#x2026;\" tabindex=\"0\" role=\"note\" aria-label=\"Accepted\">\r\n                <div class=\"ta-center\">\r\n                    <svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"svg-icon iconCheckmarkLg\" width=\"36\" height=\"36\" viewBox=\"0 0 36 36\"><path d=\"m6 14 8 8L30 6v8L14 30l-8-8v-8Z\"/></svg>\r\n                </div>\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n    \r\n        <a class=\"js-post-issue flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer py6 mx-auto\" href=\"/posts/375857/timeline\" data-shortcut=\"T\" data-ks-title=\"timeline\" data-controller=\"s-tooltip\" data-s-tooltip-placement=\"right\" title=\"Show activity on this post.\" aria-label=\"Timeline\"><svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"mln2 mr0 svg-icon iconHistory\" width=\"19\" height=\"18\" viewBox=\"0 0 19 18\"><path d=\"M3 9a8 8 0 1 1 3.73 6.77L8.2 14.3A6 6 0 1 0 5 9l3.01-.01-4 4-4-4h3L3 9Zm7-4h1.01L11 9.36l3.22 2.1-.6.93L10 10V5Z\"/></svg></a>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n        </div>\r\n\r\n        \r\n\r\n<div class=\"answercell post-layout--right\">\r\n    \r\n    <div class=\"s-prose js-post-body\" itemprop=\"text\">\r\n<p>This answer is a test</p>\n<p>Formatting:\n<code>codeblock</code>,</p>\n<p><a href=\"https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812\">link</a>,</p>\n<p><strong>bold</strong></p>\n<p>Big codeblock:</p>\n<pre class=\"lang-js prettyprint-override\"><code>console.log(&quot;codeblock works&quot;) // test comment in codeblock\n</code></pre>\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"mt24\">\r\n        <div class=\"d-flex fw-wrap ai-start jc-end gs8 gsy\">\r\n            <time itemprop=\"dateCreated\" datetime=\"2022-02-02T15:40:17\"></time>\r\n            <div class=\"flex--item mr16\" style=\"flex: 1 1 100px;\">\r\n                \r\n\r\n\r\n<div class=\"js-post-menu pt2\" data-post-id=\"375857\">\r\n    <div class=\"d-flex gs8 s-anchors s-anchors__muted fw-wrap\">\r\n\r\n            <div class=\"flex--item\">\r\n                <a href=\"/a/375857\"\r\n                   rel=\"nofollow\"\r\n                   itemprop=\"url\"\r\n                   class=\"js-share-link js-gps-track\"\r\n                   title=\"Short permalink to this answer\"\r\n                   data-gps-track=\"post.click({ item: 2, priv: 0, post_type: 2 })\"\r\n                   data-controller=\"se-share-sheet\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-title=\"Share a link to this answer\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-subtitle=\"\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-post-type=\"answer\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-social=\"facebook twitter \"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-location=\"2\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-license-url=\"https%3a%2f%2fcreativecommons.org%2flicenses%2fby-sa%2f4.0%2f\"\r\n                   data-se-share-sheet-license-name=\"CC BY-SA 4.0\"\r\n                   data-s-popover-placement=\"bottom-start\">Share</a>\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n                    <div class=\"flex--item\">\r\n                        <a href=\"/posts/375857/edit\" class=\"js-suggest-edit-post js-gps-track\" data-gps-track=\"post.click({ item: 6, priv: 0, post_type: 2 })\" title=\"\">Improve this answer</a>\r\n                    </div>\r\n\r\n            <div class=\"flex--item\">\r\n                <button type=\"button\"\r\n                        id=\"btnFollowPost-375857\" class=\"s-btn s-btn__link js-follow-post js-follow-answer js-gps-track\"\r\n                        data-gps-track=\"post.click({ item: 14, priv: 0, post_type: 2 })\"\r\n                        data-controller=\"s-tooltip \" data-s-tooltip-placement=\"bottom\"\r\n                        data-s-popover-placement=\"bottom\" aria-controls=\"\"\r\n                        title=\"Follow this answer to receive notifications\">\r\n                    Follow\r\n                </button>\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"js-menu-popup-container\"></div>\r\n</div>\r\n            </div>\r\n            <div class=\"post-signature flex--item fl0\">\r\n<div class=\"user-info \">\r\n    <div class=\"user-action-time\">\r\n        <a href=\"/posts/375857/revisions\" title=\"show all edits to this post\"\r\n                         class=\"js-gps-track\"\r\n                         data-gps-track=\"post.click({ item: 4, priv: 0, post_type: 2 })\">edited <span title=\"2022-03-21 17:35:45Z\" class=\"relativetime\">13 secs ago</span></a>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-gravatar32\">\r\n        \r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n        \r\n        <div class=\"-flair\">\r\n            \r\n        </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n            <div class=\"post-signature flex--item fl0\">\r\n                <div class=\"user-info\">\r\n    <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n        <span class=\"community-wiki\" title=\"This post is community owned as of Feb 2 at 15:40. Votes do not generate reputation, and it can be edited by users with 100 rep\">\r\n            community wiki\r\n        </span>\r\n    </div><br>\r\n    <div class=\"user-details\">\r\n        <a id=\"history-375857\" href=\"/posts/375857/revisions\" title=\"show revision history for this post\">\r\n        3 revs<br><a href=\"/users/1091095\">MrMythical</a>\r\n        </a>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n        \r\n    \r\n    </div>\r\n    \r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n            <span class=\"d-none\" itemprop=\"commentCount\">1</span> \r\n    <div class=\"post-layout--right js-post-comments-component\">\r\n        <div id=\"comments-375857\" class=\"comments js-comments-container bt bc-black-075 mt12  dno\" data-post-id=\"375857\" data-min-length=\"15\">\r\n            <ul class=\"comments-list js-comments-list\"\r\n                    data-remaining-comments-count=\"1\"\r\n                    data-canpost=\"false\"\r\n                    data-cansee=\"true\"\r\n                    data-comments-unavailable=\"false\"\r\n                    data-addlink-disabled=\"true\">\r\n\r\n            </ul>\r\n\t    </div>\r\n\r\n        <div id=\"comments-link-375857\" data-rep=5 data-anon=true>\r\n                    <a class=\"js-add-link comments-link dno\" title=\"Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like &#x201C;&#x2B;1&#x201D; or &#x201C;thanks&#x201D;.\"  href=\"#\" role=\"button\"></a>\r\n                <span class=\"js-link-separator dno\">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>\r\n            <a class=\"js-show-link comments-link \" title=\"Expand to show all comments on this post\" href=# onclick=\"\" role=\"button\">Show <b>1</b> more comment</a>\r\n        </div>         \r\n    </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n","VotesCastJson":[]}
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2:12733)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2:18786)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2:21594)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2:7320)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2:24109)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2:24676)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2:406)
    at Object.<anonymous> (full-anon.en.js?v=920cc57ec2ed:1:128576)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:28768)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
```

I am using Google Chrome, and this seems to also be the case on Meta Stack Overflow (where I discovered it). It might be like this on more sites

Comment: Already reported and [tag:status-review]: [Loading posts in real time is broken in some cases due to a breaking change in the format data is returned](/q/376823/289905).

Comment: This appears to have been fixed recently.